# Why a low pass filter across relay contacts instead of a high pass filter?

Tags: power, relay, snubber, transient-suppression

I have found a [snubber](https://www.redlion.net/sites/default/files/213/3926/SNUB%20Product%20Manual.pdf), it is a low pass filter. It doesn't make sense to have a low pass filter across the contact. I would consider transients such as arcing to be high frequency; therefore, a high pass filter across relay makes sense in order to avoid arcing across contact. Higher frequency signals can pass through the snubber.  Can anyone tell me why there is a low pass filter across relay contacts?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How does a series capacitor pass low frequencies?

Comment: Think of the ultimate low frequency - DC. Will that pass through?

Comment: @Transistor  Frequency: DC to 62Hz (in the highlighted image above). Is this talking above the power line or is it talking about the frequency that it allows to pass?

Comment: @Sam it's talking about the power line. Since the RC is a high pass filter, it will not be passing DC

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The snubber provides a lossy path for the inductor flyback. It's essentially a high-pass filter that shunts the flyback spike past the opening switch back to the power supply, dissipating some of that energy in the resistor, as heat.

The snubber can also be placed across the coil so the spike energy is shunted locally at the coil, although this wastes AC power when the coil is energized.

The RC values chosen are a compromise between catching enough of the spike to prevent arcing as the switch opens, and dissipating power while switch is open (for an AC line frequency of up to 62Hz.)

The optimum values depend on the coil and the voltage in use. In this case they've settled on a maximum flyback pulse voltage of 1200V with this specific coil.

Comment: In the image highlighted above, it mentions frequency of DC to 62Hz. Is it talking about the power line or is it mentioning that it allows low frequency to pass through?

Comment: They’re saying that they’ve sized the RC to have moderate losses at up to 62Hz. Above that the losses would increase (say, if this were used for 400Hz.)

Answer (score 4):

it's a actually high pass, thus it's only usable at the low frequencies.

at higher frequencies there is too much heating in the resistor.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a snubber is to *absorb energy* and dissipate it as heat.  A filter made of ideal inductors and capacitors would will absorb energy some of the time, but any energy it absorbs beyond a fixed capacity will always need to be returned to the surrounding circuit.  If an LC filter were placed across a relay contact, and absorb energy when the contact opened, then when the contact closed it the filter would produce an oscillating current waveform which holds the energy as a shifting mixture of capacitor voltages and inductor currents.  If the LC filter was made of ideal components and the relay contact and conducting wires were all ideal conductors, the energy could be held forever while the currents oscillate, but if there's any resistance anyplace that would cause energy to get converted into heat.  If a snubber network didn't contain any deliberate resistance, the energy would be converted to heat within inductors, capacitors, wires, or contacts that aren't designed for that purpose.  If one adds resistors to the network, most of the energy will get converted to energy within the resistors which can easily be constructed to dissipate it more effectively than other components.

Answer (score 0):

> I have found a snubber, it is a low pass filter.

No, it isn't.

A series R-C network is a high-pass filter.  It has a low impedance at high frequencies (set by the resistance of the resistor), and a high impedance at low frequencies (set by the reactance of the capacitor plus the resistance of the resistor).

You are confusing this with a single-pole R-C network where the output is taken from the resistor-capacitor node.  In that circuit, because the capacitor is in the shunt leg rather than in series with the output, the capacitor has a low-pass effect.